# Sexuality question

Tags: sex

What do you call a supposedly straight man, whose first preference is a straight man, and whose second sexual preference would be a straight or bisexual woman that looked a little bit like a man. Would that be a transgendered lesbian, or what?

Answer (score 6):

I don't believe this question falls under the scope of WorldBuilding, but I do know that your proposed character would likely be considered a bisexual with a masculine preference. Gender dysphoria--the condition that causes one to be labelled as "transgender"--would not come into play unless the character in question does not identify with his assigned-at-birth sex.